# Django, how to extract values list monthly from DateField?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have the following models:

```
class Materiale(models.Model):
    sottocategoria = models.ForeignKey(Sottocategoria, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    quantita=models.DecimalField(')
    prezzo=models.DecimalField()
    data=models.DateField(default="GG/MM/YYYY")
```

I wanna calculate the value given by the following expressions `PREZZO*QUANTIA` in a monthly's view (in other words the total sum of `PRZZO*QUANTITA` of all items in a single month), but my code does not work:

```
Monthly_views=Materiale.objects.filter(data__year='2020').values_list('month').annotate(totale_mensile=F(('quantita')*F('prezzo')))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`values()`** method instead of **`values_list()`**

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

result = Materiale.objects.annotate(totale_mensile=F('quantita') * F('prezzo')
                           ).values('data__month').annotate(totale_mensile_sum=Sum('totale_mensile')))
```

or simply

```
result = Materiale.objects.values('data__month').annotate(totale_mensile_sum=Sum(F('quantita') * F('prezzo')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try filtering by month also

```py
Monthly_views=Materiale.objects.filter(data__year='2020').filter(data_month='4')
```